# "Invalid path for Logical Volume" in boot.log

Tags: boot, grub2, swap, hibernate, uuid

I am getting the following messages in my `/var/log/boot.log`:

> lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit
>     "disk/by-uuid/db9c53d1-9f64-4bb7-970c-9fce38b499d4": Invalid path for Logical Volume.

The UUID is my swap partition, which is also used for hibernation.
By trying out different config options I was able to trace the root of the message to my grub configuration.

My `/etc/default/grub` looks like the following:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="resume=UUID=db9c53d1-9f64-4bb7-970c-9fce38b499d4   other-option=value"
```

For reference my `/etc/fstab`:

```
# <file system>                           <mount point>   <type>  <options>         <dump>  <pass>
# sda4 
UUID=38a2c53b-2a10-4653-8869-b819c1b0c3be /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# sda5
UUID=51cd4543-09c0-4eb6-959a-692991c4429e /home           ext4    defaults          0       2
# sda2
UUID=db9c53d1-9f64-4bb7-970c-9fce38b499d4 none            swap    sw                0       0
# sda1
UUID=36A8-4C49                            /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077        0       1
```

I already tried lots of different settings to fix this error message, including uninstalling LVM2, since I do not use any logical volumes.

Does anybody know how to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 1):

**Old answer:**

Just found the solution by chance browsing some more blogs.
See the following comment by Brandon Beck: http://chriseiffel.com/uncategorized/step-by-step-how-to-get-hibernate-working-for-linux-ubuntu-11-04-mint-11/#comment-116

I had to change /etc/default/grub to use the PARTUUID of the swap partition instead of UUID like this:

> "resume=PARTUUID=..."

You can get the PARTUUID of the swap partition with `blkid`.
Afterwards, run `sudo update-grub`.

**Revised answer:**

After changing the grub entry to PARTUUID hibernation did not work anymore. Maybe /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume needs to be adapted accordingly.

However, I just reformatted my swap partition, which was previously created by Clonezilla, and updated all config files with the new UUID.
I also switched back /etc/default/grub to use UUID for "resume" and entered the new one.
Now, hibernation works again and the error message in boot.log also disappeared. Problem seems to be finally resolved.